# Crons not running - CentOS

Tags: cron

I have two cron jobs which are not running. Is there anything wrong with them?

```
5   *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/com/cron/cron.php

7   *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/com/cron/weekly-mail.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing the user:

```
5    *   *   *   *  root /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/com/cron/cron.php

7    *   *   *   *  root /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/com/cron/weekly-mail.php
```

Comment: Hi. Made the changes, waiting to see if I get the notification emails.

Comment: maybe root is not the best user to do that job. It might me better to use the user Apache / Nginx etc to run the scripts. To debug you should run the script manually